# SUMIFS of data in other sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to  use the google-sheets SUMIFS formula to summarise the total dollar amount of invoices sent each month, however I get an error "array arguments to sumifs are of different size".

```
=sumifs('Invoices Sent'!J:J,'Invoices Sent'!B:B,">="&A2, ' Invoices Sent'!B:B,"<"&A3)
```

The invoice dollar amount is in the sheet 'Invoices Sent' in Column J.
The invoice date for each invoice  is in the sheet 'Invoices Sent' in Column B.

I am not sure if the error is telling me that I need to specify a finite range for B and J. I have tried to express the range explicitly but that doesn't seem to help. I don't want to explicitly state the dollar and date row start and end indexes as I would like not to have to update the formula as more rows are added. Most examples I have found don't access another sheet, and have explicit ranges from criteria_1 and criteria_2.

What can I do to resolve this issue ?

Any help is appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `' Invoices Sent'!B:B` with `'Invoices Sent'!B:B` and you should be good to go...

Comment: Thanks @rockinfreakshow. I didn't see that. The error message didn't help